# Command 'near' not found

Tags: nearprotocol

I am using these instructions to generate public and private keys for an account (testnet) to do some test transactions.

https://docs.near.org/docs/tokens/token-custody#option-2-self-custody

I run this command on terminal

```
npm install -g near-cli
```

and then this command to generate the key

```
near generate-key dummyaccount.testnet
```

but it says

```
Command 'near' not found
```

any idea what am I missing here (sorry just got started with this thing).

npm  7.23.0
node 12.18.2

Comment: Search this site for *command not found*. There are many existing questions here asking the same thing that have already been answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you done this?:

> “If Node modules are installed in a place inaccessible by your OS
> user, you need to do `chown -R $USER /path/to/destination/` or the
> equivalent on your OS.”

https://docs.near.org/docs/tokens/token-custody#to-generate-public-keys-via-cli

Comment: yes the issue was related to this, installing the related libraries again with 'sudo' did the job

Comment: The link is broken. Any idea where that page lives now? Thanks.

Comment: @Ryan 
https://docs.near.org/docs/videos/accounts-keys

Comment: https://wiki.near.org/overview/tokenomics/token-custody#option-2-self-custody

Answer (score 0):

```
npx near generate-key dummyaccount.testnet
```

This worked for me. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that `near-cli` is no longer being maintained

A new tool has been introduced recently that helps to interact with NEAR Protocol from the command line

Follow the link to find installation options as well as documentation:
https://github.com/near/near-cli-rs

It's got cool features that make interacting with the network as easy as possible, and the installation process was made extremely simple, preventing issues like the one mentioned in the question

[image]